# Adding a listview as on of the views that can be selected in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, fragment, navigation-drawer

First off; I would like to apologize for the lengthy question. I though this was the only way to get across what I am trying to do. Anyway. I have an app that user a navigation drawer that will offer a user 3 choices. I want Test1Fragment to be a listview. I can not seem to figure out how to make this happen. Please help.

MainActivity method that controls which fragment is loaded based on the selection:

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Test1Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Test2Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Test3Fragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Test1Fragment:

```
public class Test1Fragment extends Fragment {


public Test1Fragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

fragment_create.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/txtLabel"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
    <!--android:text="Create View"-->
    <!--android:textSize="16dp" />-->

<!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_action_copy" />-->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I understand that I am missing code for the listview, but this is all I want int the xml view.

Thank you

Comment: post your `R.layout.fragment_create`

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, your layout code should look in example like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your class, you must fill listview with data. You have to create adapter and attach data to this adapter. Then adapter must be passed to listview.
Quick example :

```
public class Test1Fragment extends Fragment { 

//No need for empty constructor, it is made by default
//public Test1Fragment() { 
//} 

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);

   ListView listView =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_fragment_listView);

   String[] items = { "Milk", "Cheese", "Cucumber", "Toilet", "Duck" };

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}
```

This way you will have filled listview with strings from array items.
This is very basic example, you can extend also base adapter, and populate it with your own objects and views.

Here is screenshot with result : [image: list]

Comment: I have tried this once before and it will not work. First, I can not use findViewById (I am assuming because the class is a frag). The error is "Can resolve method" Second, I get the error "Cannot resolve constructor"  for arrayAdapter code (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

Comment: Check my answer, I fixed constructor from "this"-> "getActivity()", 
and you can now use findViewById just by calling after cast your root layout. Hope it helps.